# WSO2 API Manager service API call failure while loading throttling policy

Tags: web-services, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-api-manager

Currently we are trying to expose our Axis2 web services via WSO2 API manager. However in some cases service do not return result and looking at logs on WSO2 API manager we see the following

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler} -  Unable         to load throttling policy using key: gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler} TID: [0] [AM] [2013-01-07 16:42:22,951]  
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /TestService/1.0.0, WSAction: urn:testOperation, SOAPAction: urn:testOperation, MessageID: urn:uuid:a8f94f58-5e2d-4d51-afc7-83182b51d173, Direction: request, STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unable to load throttling policy using key: gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><p:testOperation xmlns:p="http://example.com"><param>d1</param></p:testOperation></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

For configuration i use the default h2 database as registry and mysql database for user and api manager database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a known issue [1],which will be fixed in the next AM release. We also encountered this issue at a instance,when we are trying invoking two different APIs at same time or within short time period.

Thanks;

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-835

Comment: I see for information we do not use a keymanager/gateway seperated setup like described in the Jira. So local setups also faces this kind of problem.